# Execute shell script everytime a new user is created

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

What would be the easiest way to execute a command everytime a new user is added?

I checked through `/etc/adduser.conf` but nothing is in there which looks like it will do this?

I thought about added it to the users `.bashrc` so it jsut executes when they login, but I would rather have it setup before they have logged in.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want it to run on a login shell, `.bash_profile` is the place to put it. If you put it in `.bashrc`, it will run when they start non-login shells (and in login shells if `.bash_profile` includes `.bashrc`).

Comment: @lnductiveload That's the thing... those scripts will only run when the new user actually login - I want the script to run as soon as I have added the new user.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From `man adduser`:

```
   If  the  file  /usr/local/sbin/adduser.local exists, it will be exe‐
   cuted after the user account has been set up  in  order  to  do  any
   local setup.  The arguments passed to adduser.local are:
   username uid gid home-directory
```

Looks like you can add your user-creation actions here.

Comment: You also may want to `chmod +x adduser.local`.

Comment: This might be distro-specific to Debian and its offspring, at least it's absent in RHEL et al.

Comment: Can we run another `chmod +x` shell script from `adduser.local`? I was trying that but its not able to locate the .sh file, the shell script works fine in terminal.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, did you manage to do something in an RHEL/Centos machine for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know direct way...
But, you can check for changes in `/etc/passwd` file or `/home directrory`, using, for example `inotifywait` or using some cron job.

Answer (score 1):

I did this some years ago writing a custom script that does everithing I need and calling `adduser` inside the script to add the user to the system.